# File Allocation Table Reading

Tags: c#, filesystems, fat32, fat

I am working on a custom FAT file system explorer and things have been going quite well. However, I want to know if there is a better way to efficiently read/write to the chainmap. For large devices, this can be incredible resource intensive and it can be very, very slow. Especially when allocation space.

Here is how I read it:

```
    public void ReadChainMap()
    {
        chainMap = new uint[clusterCount];
        fx.Io.SeekTo(chainMapOffset);
        EndianIo io = new EndianIo(fx.Io.In.ReadBytes((int)chainMapSize), EndianType.BigEndian);
        io.Open();

        for (int x = 0; x < clusterCount; x++)
            chainMap[x] = (chainMapEntrySize == 2) ?
                io.In.ReadUInt16() : io.In.ReadUInt32();


        io.Close();
    }
```

The chain can sometimes be hundreds of megabytes.

And this is how I write it. When allocation and modifications to the chainMap uint array have been done, it will basically loop through that uint array and rewrite the entire chainmap.

```
    public void WriteChainMap()
    {
        EndianIo io = new EndianIo(new byte[chainMapSize],
            EndianType.BigEndian);
        io.Open(); io.SeekTo(0);

        for (int x = 0; x < clusterCount; x++)
            if (chainMapEntrySize == 2)
                io.Out.Write((ushort)chainMap[x]);
            else
                io.Out.Write(chainMap[x]);

        fx.Io.SeekTo(chainMapOffset);
        fx.Io.Out.Write(io.ToArray());
    }
```

I have been working on a cache system, but I want to have some more ideas on how to make this better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could segment it somehow.  Rather than read/write the whole thing, 'page in/out' chunks based on usage.  Think about virtual memory systems for inspiration there.

Comment: Well, the thing is, when allocating, you need to have it ready (in memory being the easiest) and loop through the thing until you find a free cluster. And you would do that for how many clusters a file needs. Now if I loop through the chainmap on the device and read the integer value, that would be significantly slower than reading it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot of research and testing on binary serialization myself and one thing that struck me was that you could read pretty big blocks quickly with todays harddrives and that the lion part of time was actually spent converting bytes into integers, strings etc.

So, one thing you could do is rearchitecture to make use of all your cores, first read as big block of data as possibly and then use PLINQ or Parallel.net to do the actual deserialization. You might even want to go even further into a producer/consumer pattern. You'll only see gains for large number of entries or large blocks or data though otherwise it's usually not worth parallelizing.

Also, you have a seek statement, those are always expensive, try using a memorymappedfile  or reading a big block right away if possible and applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, thought this was dead, haha. I did come up with a solution. I looped through the allocation table and recorded only the free clusters and then saved them to a file. I then open that file when I need to write new data and it will have the next free cluster ready. Only drawback is that it can take a while to cache on very large drives.